# How to insert Tooltip into incidence plot?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, tooltip, labeling

I'm trying to make a graph using a file `.NET` extracted from a file `.CSV` and to make tooltiped the vertices' labels.

Initially I have extracted an `IncidentMatrix` and then `VertexLabels`.

```
IncidenceGraph[
 IncidenceMatrix[Import["C:\\Users\\Network.net"]], 
 AbsoluteOptions[Import["C:\\Users\\Network.net"], VertexLabels]]
```

I wasn't able to made it by using `Placed`. What else can i do?

For example,
I define an array that contains all labels and an incidence matrix:

`Labels = {1 -> "One", 2 -> "Two", 3 -> "Three"};
Matrix = {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1};
Graph[Matrix, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed[Labels, Tooltip]]`

But it the only one label viewed is "Three".
I can also use a code like this:

`Matrix = {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1};
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, 
 VertexLabels -> {1 -> Placed["one", Tooltip], 
   2 -> Placed["two", Tooltip], 3 -> Placed["three", Tooltip]}]` 
But in this case I'm supposed to insert the labels one by one.

Comment: How does your work set differ from the documentation example `IncidenceGraph[( {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}} ), EdgeLabels -> Placed["Name", Tooltip]]`?  Can you give us a self-contained example where that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matrix = {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1};
labels = {1 -> "One", 2 -> "Two", 3 -> "Three"};
```

You can modify `labels` programmatically using

```
labels1 = (# -> Placed[#2, Tooltip] & @@@ labels);
```

or using

```
labels2 = MapAt[Placed[#, Tooltip] &, labels, {All, -1}];
```

Alternatively, you can use the function `Property` to set the `VertexLabels` for each vertex:

```
labeledvertices = Property[#, VertexLabels -> Placed[#2, Tooltip]] & @@@ labels;
```

All three methods give the same result:

```
g1 = Graph[matrix, VertexLabels -> labels1];
g2 = Graph[matrix, VertexLabels -> labels2];
g3 = Graph[labeledvertices, matrix];

Grid[{{"g1", "g2", "g3"}, {g1, g2, g3}}, Frame -> {All, None}]
```

[image]